# How to wait between functions

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, wait

I want to do the following without using Thread.sleep.Basically I have to call 3 functions with some wait time between each of them and run the whole thing over a loop for 100 times.

I tried using the Timer class,but it seems I am using it incorrectly.

```
   func test()
 for(int i=0;i<100;i++){
      func A()
      wait for 20 seconds
      func B()
      wait for 45 seconds
      func C()
      wait for 2 mins
}//repeat for 100 times
```

Comment: Why can't you use Thread.Sleep ? It releases the thread while waiting so it seems ideal if you need a delay.

Comment: Why don't you want to use Thread.Sleep?  That's exactly what it is designed for.

Comment: @driis: It doesn't "release" the thread - it's not like the thread is available for other work. It doesn't take significant CPU, but I wouldn't call that "releasing" it.

Comment: You are missing some part of you sample that shows how you "tried using the Timer".

Comment: I answered too quickly and misread the requirement that you dont want to use Thread.Sleep(): could you please specify which kind of application it is ? A console application that runs in the task scheduler, a windows service, a part of a client application... ?

Comment: Are you wanting func A to run every 20 seconds for 100 times, func b every 45 seconds and c every 2 mins? Or are you deliberately running them (and waiting) between callings?

Comment: I would use a `Timer` unless you have some more specific requirements.

Comment: You can let the OS do the wait for you like with Thread.Sleep or waiting on a semaphore with a timeout which is full. The only other option is to busy wait in some form of while loop until the time has elapsed. Do you want to do something different in the meantime on this thread?

Comment: It doesn't really make sense that you want to "wait" 20 seconds here, 45 seconds there, 2 minutes there.  If you can clarify that, you will likely get a more applicable answer.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: @driis: `Thread.Sleep` releases the *CPU*, not the thread. The CPU can immediately start doing other work, while the thread itself can do nothing until the wait completes.

Answer (score 2):

You might be looking for the Task framework.  You can do something like this:

```
async void Run()
{
    for (int i=0; i<100; i++)
    {
        A();
        await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20));
        B();
        await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(45));
        C();
        await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(2));
    }
}
```

The function will return immediately, but that loop will keep running in the background.

Edit: As svick noted below, this is a new .NET 4.5 feature.

Comment: Good answer. This is essentially what I was writing, but using a `Timer` explicitly, which turns out to be a nasty bit of work.

Comment: You might want to add that you will need VS2012 for this.

Answer (score 0):

I'm gonna go and make a big assumption (all clues point in that direction):

I'm presuming you're doing all of this in Windows Forms and you would like the GUI not to freeze during the Thread.Sleep() invocations, right ? If that is the case then you could write this method:

```
public static class Foo {
  public static void MySleep(int milliseconds) {
    int startTick = Environment.TickCount;
    while (Environment.TickCount - startTick < milliseconds)
      Application.DoEvents();
  }
}
```

and then replace the Thread.Sleep invocations with Foo.MySleep invocations (but **BEWARE** of the implications of Application.DoEvents, which allows the entire process to be executed all over again while the control is inside of any MySleep invocations. **I don't recommend** doing things this way if you don't take precautions -- for instance you should always disable the button that calls **func test()** while **test** is executing because it can get executed again and again in a never ending recursion) :

```
func test()
  for(int i=0;i<100;i++){
    func A()
    Foo.MySleep(20 * 1000);
    func B()
    Foo.MySleep(45 * 1000);
    func C()
    Foo.MySleep(2 * 60 * 1000);
}//repeat for 100 times
```

There is another way (a bit safer) of doing just that.
It involves a secondary thread and some Control.Invoke calls. It also allows you to use the standard System.Thread.Sleep(int milliseconds) method.

And it goes something like this:

```
public class Form1 : Form {

  public void triggerTestAndReturnImmediately() {
    new Thread(start: () => {

      Action callA = () => funcA();
      Action callB = () => funcB();
      Action callC = () => funcC();

      for(int i=0;i<100;i++){
        this.Invoke(callA);
        Thread.Sleep(20 * 1000);

        this.Invoke(callB);
        Thread.Sleep(45 * 1000);

        this.Invoke(callC);
        Thread.Sleep(2 * 60 * 1000);
      }//repeat for 100 times


    }).Start();
  }

}
```

The "this.Invoke( someDelegate )" bit is based on the fact that the method "triggerTestAndReturnImmediately" is a member of a Form subclass and "this" is a Form instance.

What goes on here is that you run the waiting operations + the triggering of actual workers (funcA, funcB, funcC) on a separate thread. Why do you run only the trigerring of the actual workers and not the actual workers themselves ? Because you're most likely going to access the GUI objects from those funcs and that is not permitted in WinForms (and many other .NET or non .NET GUI frameworks for that matter).

So you're asking the GUI thread (which as you pointed out in your question) must be free in 99% of the time to execute those functions - hence the this.Invoke ( someDelegate ) invocations.

You should take the same precautions I mentioned earlier but all that is up to you and what you want your application to do. Presuming you want to have a button's Click event handler call the **triggerTestAndReturnImmediately** and you want it to be disabled during the process, how would you go about disabling and reenabling the button ?

If you do this:

```
void buttonBar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  this.buttonBar.Enabled = false;
  this.triggerTestAndReturnImmediately();
  this.buttonBar.Enabled = true;
}
```

then that wouldn't do you any good, because the **triggerTestAndReturnImmediately** method does just what it's name implies: "it returns immediately".

So how would you pull this off ? You could do something like:

```
void buttonBar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  this.triggerTestAndReturnImmediately();
}


  public void triggerTestAndReturnImmediately() {
    this.buttonBar.Enabled = false;

    new Thread(start: () => {

      Action callA = () => funcA();
      Action callB = () => funcB();
      Action callC = () => funcC();
      Action reenableButton = () => this.buttonBar.Enabled = true;

      for(int i=0;i<100;i++){
        this.Invoke(callA);
        Thread.Sleep(20 * 1000);

        this.Invoke(callB);
        Thread.Sleep(45 * 1000);

        this.Invoke(callC);
        Thread.Sleep(2 * 60 * 1000);

        this.Invoke(reenableButton);
      }//repeat for 100 times


    }).Start();
  }
```

Also make sure you always reenable the button whether the invocation sequence crashes or not with some **try finally** statement or other gymnastics.

So I think you can get an idea of what the precautions I was talking about are (they depend on what you want your app to do).